# How to retrieve and show data on screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui

I am storing simple data in core data which i want to retrieve and show on screen, but I am not sure how and where should I write that code to show it on screen as I am always get out of bound error..

Also not all data is saving at time its only saving when i scroll til bottom

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.title, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    @StateObject private var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
    

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            NavigationView {
                ScrollView {

                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()),
                                             count: UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad ? 4 : 2)) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.results, id: \.self) {
                            let viewModel = ResultVM(model: $0)
                            NavigationLink(destination: {
                                DetailView(data: viewModel.trackName)
                            }, label: {
                                SearchResultRow(resultVM: viewModel, coreDM: PersistenceController())
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onAppear(perform: {
                viewModel.performSearch()
            })
        }
    }
}

struct SearchResultRow: View {

    let resultVM: ResultVM
    let coreDM: PersistenceController

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill(.yellow)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .overlay(Text(resultVM.trackName)) // want to show data from Core data here
        }.padding()
            .background(Color.red)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                coreDM.saveResult(title: resultVM.trackName)
            })
    }
}
```

Data showing from API which same data storing in CoreData

[image]

[image]

Method to save and retrieve (which is working fine)

```
func saveResult(title: String) {
    let result =  Item(context: container.viewContext)
    result.title = title

    do {
        try container.viewContext.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("error")
    }
}

func getResult() -> [Item] {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()

    do {
       return try container.viewContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
    }
    catch {
        return []
    }
}
```

API call

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class HomeViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var results = [ResultItem]()
    func performSearch() {
        guard let gUrl = URL(
            string: "https://api.artic.edu/api/v1/artworks"
        ) else { return }

        Task {
            do {
                let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: gUrl)
                let response = try JSONDecoder()
                    .decode(ResponseData.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                    self?.results = response.data ?? []
                }
            } catch {
                print("*** ERROR ***")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use items from the wrapper instead of viewModel.results in the loop. NSFetchRequest doesn’t listen to the store.

Comment: @loremipsum Thank you for input..Can you please elaborate ? as I am trying to fetch data from coreData in foreachloop I am getting error as "A fetch request must have an entity"

Comment: The only time I have seen that is with the way you are getting the .fetchRequest() in the method. The Swift built in method is very unreliable. Just use the items you have in the view

Answer (score 0):

Remove the view model we don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. The `View` struct stores the view data and does dependency tracking, and the property wrappers give it external change tracking features like an object. If you add an actual object on top you'll get consistency bugs that SwiftUI was designed to eliminate. So first remove this:

```
@StateObject private var viewModel = HomeViewModel()
```

You already have the fetch request property wrapper and as I said that gives the `View` change tracking, so when the `items` change (e.g. an item is added, removed or moved), the `body` will be called, so simply use it in your `ForEach` like this:

```
ForEach(items) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: {
                            DetailView(item: item)
                        }, label: {
                            SearchResultRow(item: item)
                        })
                    }
```

Then use `@ObservedObject` in your subview, this gives the `View` the ability to track changes to the item so body will be called when the item's properties change, like `item.title`. Do the same in the `DetailView`.

```
struct SearchResultRow: View {

    @ObservedObject var item: Item
```

It seems to me you are trying to download and cache data in Core Data. That is unnecessary since you can simply set a NSURLCache on the NSURLSession and it will automatically cache it for you, it even works if offline. However if you really want to cache it yourself in Core Data then the architecture should be your UI fetches it from Core Data and then you have another object somewhere responsible for syncing down the remote data into Core Data. Normally this would be at the `App` struct level not in the View appearing. When the data is saved to core data the managed object context context will be changed which the `@FetchRequest` is listening for and `body` will be called.

Comment: viewModel = HomeViewModel() will it require for calling API ? I have updated my question. for ex.  viewModel.performSearch()

Comment: No we don't use an object and onAppear for that anymore. We use the new task modifier which is called at onAppear and the View manages the lifecycle of the download, cancelling it if necessary. However in your case I don't believe you want to do this syncing of the remote data to the local store when the view appears, it would be better if you moved it into your persistence layer.

Comment: Also if you are just trying to cache the downloaded data you would be better just setting a NSURLCache on your NSURLSession then its automatic.

Comment: Thank you...my only doubt is how can i call API from  "HomeViewModel" in view.. if i remove this  "viewModel.performSearch()" I will not able to fetch API data

Comment: I added some info to the bottom of my answer

Comment: Also first time (on fresh start) I am not getting any data in item because nothing is saved in code data before that